# Encountered an error when using CnosDB constants

Tags: cnosdb

```
    oceanic_station ❯ SELECT CAST (1 AS TIMESTAMP);
    422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010016","error_message":"Auth error: The user root not found"}
```

Sorry, as a beginner, I encountered the following error when using the cnosdb constant CAST. I have been researching for a while but I don't understand what's going on. Has anyone encountered this before?

Document address:

[enter link description here](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/sql.html#data-types)